# How to avoid calling a function multiple times

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT c.c_epasts,DATE_PART('day', now() - (
  SELECT _get_1_darba_iestasanas.pirma_iestasanas
  FROM _get_1_darba_iestasanas(c.c_id) _get_1_darba_iestasanas(did integer, pirma_iestasanas date)
  LIMIT 1
)) AS worked_days
FROM cilveks c 
WHERE worked_days = ANY ('{182,273,365}'::int[]) AND (SELECT count(*) FROM sertifikati_lietotaji s WHERE s.id_cilveks=c.c_id)=0
```

I dont want to make this function in SELECT and in WHERE statements (both). Because it increases query execution time.

How can I make it that this function is executed only one time and I can select value and that value use in where clause?

```
DATE_PART('day', now() - (
  SELECT _get_1_darba_iestasanas.pirma_iestasanas
  FROM _get_1_darba_iestasanas(c.c_id) _get_1_darba_iestasanas(did integer, pirma_iestasanas date)
LIMIT 1))
```

Comment: This: `_get_1_darba_iestasanas(c.c_id) _get_1_darba_iestasanas(did integer, pirma_iestasanas date)` is invalid syntax. That can't be the query you are using.

Comment: But it is working :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap this in a derived table:

```
select * 
from (
  SELECT c.c_epasts,
            DATE_PART('day', now() - (
               SELECT _get_1_darba_iestasanas.pirma_iestasanas
               FROM _get_1_darba_iestasanas(c.c_id) _get_1_darba_iestasanas(did integer, pirma_iestasanas date)
               LIMIT 1)) AS worked_days
  FROM cilveks c 
  WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM sertifikati_lietotaji s WHERE s.id_cilveks=c.c_id)=0
) t
where worked_days = ANY ('{182,273,365}'::int[])
```